# Collect values from list of objects into dictionary in swift5

Tags: swift, dictionary, tuples, swift5

I have a list of Employee objects (an array of Employee objects) that consists of several properties and I would like to get a dictionary (similar to a hash map in Java) with the month and the hoursWorked. I looked at other posts but I only found examples where I can collect one of the items using map -> `.map(\.month)` but not two values

```
    struct Employee {
      var id: UUID
      var name: String
      var month: Date
      var hoursWorked: Double
      var ...
      var ...
    }
```

Sample Data - an array of Employee objects:

```
{month: 2019-01, hoursWorked: 256, id:..., name...} 
{month: 2019-02, hoursWorked: 200, id:..., name...}
{month: 2019-03, hoursWorked: 300, id:..., name...}
{month: 2019-04, hoursWorked: 150, id:..., name...}
{month: 2019-05, hoursWorked: 100, id:..., name...}
{month: 2019-06, hoursWorked: 220, id:..., name...}
.
.
.
```

Expected Result:
a Dictionary consisting of Month and hoursWorked:

```
[2019-01: 256.0]
[2019-02: 200.0]
[2019-03: 300.0]
[2019-04: 150.0]
[2019-05: 100.0]
[2019-06: 220.0]
```

...

One way to accomplish this is to loop through the Employee array and collect the month and the hoursWorked into a Swift Dictionary (Date:Double in Swift) (similar to hash map in Java). I was wondering if there is a better/simpler (perhaps, faster) way to accomplish this in Swift.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. You say you have a "list of objects." Is that an Array of your Employee structs? And you say you want a dictionary. Do you want an array of dictionaries? Do you want a dictionary that combines data for all of your Employees? What are the keys and values you want to use?

Comment: Maybe you have oversimplified your struct because it is very hard to interpret what you want (for instance is there one Employee object per employee and month). Maybe add some sample data and expected result.

Comment: I am looking to get a dictionary (similar to a Map in Java) like: month1: hours1, month2: hours2, month3: hours3.

Comment: Yes I have an array of Employee structs. I have simplified the struct showing just the two properties that I am looking to extract out of the Employee array. Essentially, I am looking to get an array of items (similar to a Map in Java) like: month1: hours1, month2: hours2, month3: hours3.... which is called as a dictionary in Swift. Hope it clarifies the question

Comment: Follow on question: is it possible to return as a tuple of the form (Date, Double) instead of a Dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce(into:_:)` function for this:

```
let dictionary = emplyees.reduce(into: [Date: Double]()) { (result, employee) in
    result[employee.month, default: 0] += employee.hoursWorked
}
```

This will create a dictionary `[Date: Double]` that have as key the month and as value the sum of hours worked for that month.

**Update**: To return an array of tuple instead, you need a little bit extra work:

```
let dictionary = emplyees.reduce(into: [(month: Date, hours: Double)]()) { (result, employee) in
    if let index = result.firstIndex(where: { $0.month == employee.month }) {
        result[index].hours += employee.hoursWorked
    } else {
        result.append((month: employee.month, hours: employee.hoursWorked))
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer! Follow on question: is it possible to return as a tuple of the form (Date, Double) instead of a Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary by grouping the array per month and then use `mapValues` and `reduce` to calculate the sum per month

```
let stats = Dictionary(grouping: employees, by: \.month)
    .mapValues { $0.reduce(into: 0, { $0 += $1.hoursWorked }) }
```

---

*Edit: here is an alternative solution based on the comment by @Alexander-ReinstateMonica*

```
extension Sequence {
    func sum() -> Element where Element: AdditiveArithmetic {
        self.reduce(.zero, +)
    }
}

let stats = Dictionary(grouping: employees, by: \.month)
    .mapValues { $0.lazy.map(\.hoursWorked).sum() }
```

---

*Edit 2: tuples instead of dictionary*

Both solution above are quite simple to convert to an array of tuples, here is the second solution as tuples sorted on month

```
let stats = Dictionary(grouping: employees, by: \.month)
    .map( { ($0.key, $0.value.lazy.map(\.hoursWorked).sum()) })
    .sorted(by: {$0.0 < $1.0})
```

Comment: Alternate: `...mapValues { $0.lazy.map(\.hoursWorked).reduce(0, +) }`. Personally I usually have an extension on `Sequence` that defines `.sum()` as `.reduce(0, +)`, which makes it read real nice. See https://forums.swift.org/t/sum-with-block/40785

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica thanks for the link, interesting stuff.

Comment: I tried to up vote your answer, but it is ending up down voting*#*#* not sure what is going on. Same thing happened to gcharita as well. Thanks for the answer!